# Why one's 127.0.0.0/8 addresses are available?

Tags: localhost, hostname

Part of my `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

When I do ping 127.7.7.7, it works!

```
PING 127.7.7.7 (127.7.7.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.7.7.7: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
64 bytes from 127.7.7.7: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
64 bytes from 127.7.7.7: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms
```

However, `ifconfig` only shows `127.0.0.1`, no mention of other addresses in 127.0.0.0/8 subnet.

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:19299 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:19299 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:1858607 (1.8 MB)  TX bytes:1858607 (1.8 MB)
```

Could you please explain why arbitrary `127.x.x.x` addresses are "enabled" answer to pings although, it seems to me, they are not mentioned anywhere explicitly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the Wikipedia article on `loopback`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost):

> IPv4 network standards reserve the entire 127.0.0.0/8 address block
>   for loopback purposes. That means any packet sent to one of those
>   16,777,214 addresses (127.0.0.1 through 127.255.255.254) is looped
>   back. IPv6 has just a single address, ::1.

Loopback means that data is sent to your own system. So, all of those addresses point to your own system.

Comment: But why one does not need to specify additional virtual interfaces?
Like lo:1, lo:2, etc...

Comment: @BulatM. Because that's how this thing is defined. The kernel knows that all of these IPs are standard and expected to loop back to the system, and it does so. You'd have to edit the kernel source to change that. See http://superuser.com/a/522240/334516 for example.